# Converting .py to exe using pyinstaller - typerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

When trying to convert my `.py` script to `.exe` file using pyinstaller I got an error: TypeError

> a bytes-like object is required not 'str'

I made a simple snake game using pygame and I'd like to convert it into `.exe` file.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (164, 199, 141)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 80)
scorefont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

pygame.display.set_caption("Wąż v1.0")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
snake_size = 10
food_size = 10


class window:
    display_width = 800
    display_height = 600
    FPS = 15

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((window.display_width, window.display_height))

def scoreMessage(score):
    text = scorefont.render("Wynik: " + str(score), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [16, 6])

def levelMessage(level):
    text = scorefont.render("Poziom: " + str(level), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, [116, 6])

def intro():
    intro = True
    cursor = 2

    with open('wynik', 'r') as f:
        wynik = sorted(map(int, f.readline().split(',')))
    print(wynik)

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    cursor = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    cursor = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and cursor == 0:
                    gameLoop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and cursor == 1:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            if cursor == 0:
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", green, 80)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", black, 80)
                message_to_screen("Graj", green, 40)
                message_to_screen("Graj", blue, 40)
                pygame.display.update()
            if cursor == 1:
                message_to_screen("Graj", green, 40)
                message_to_screen("Graj", black, 40)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", green, 80)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", blue, 80)
                pygame.display.update()
            if cursor == 2:
                gameDisplay.fill(green)
                message_to_screen("Wąż", red, -200, "large")
                message_to_screen("Graj", black, 40)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", black, 80)
                message_to_screen("Twoim celem jest zjedzenie jak największej ilości jabłek które losowo pojawiają sią na ekranie.", black, -120)
                message_to_screen("Uważaj na ściany oraz swój ogon któy wydłuża się wraz ze zjedzeniem jabłka.", black, -90)
                message_to_screen("Pamiętaj, że wraz z Twoim wynikiem zwiększa się prędkość węża.", black, -60)
                message_to_screen("Do sterowania używaj strzałek.", black, -30)
                message_to_screen("Najlepszy wynik: " + str(wynik[-1]), red, 0)
                message_to_screen("_______________________________________________________________________", black, 10)
                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(15)

def outro():
    game_over = True
    cursor2 = 2
    with open('wynik', 'r') as f:
        wynik = sorted(map(int, f.readline().split(',')))
    print(wynik)

    while game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            gameDisplay.fill(green)
            if str(score) > str(wynik[-1]):
                message_to_screen("Gratulacje, uzyskałeś najlepszy wynik!", red, -50, "medium")

            message_to_screen("Koniec gry!", red, -100, "large")
            message_to_screen("Zagraj ponownie", black, 10)
            message_to_screen("Zakończ", black, 50)

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(100)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    cursor2 = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    cursor2 = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and cursor2 == 0:
                    gameLoop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN and cursor2 == 1:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            if cursor2 == 0:
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", green, 50)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", black, 50)
                message_to_screen("Zagraj ponownie", green, 10)
                message_to_screen("Zagraj ponownie", blue, 10)
                pygame.display.update()
            if cursor2 == 1:
                message_to_screen("Zagraj ponownie", green, 10)
                message_to_screen("Zagraj ponownie", black, 10)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", green, 50)
                message_to_screen("Zakończ", blue, 50)
                pygame.display.update()



def snake(snake_size, snakeList):
    for XY in snakeList:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [XY[0], XY[1], snake_size, snake_size])


def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg, color, y_displace=0, size="small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (window.display_width / 2), (window.display_height / 2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def gameLoop():
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    x = window.display_width / 2
    y = window.display_height / 2


    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    global score
    score = 0
    level = 0
    snakeList = []
    snakeLength = 1


    randAppleX = round(random.randrange(15, window.display_width - food_size - 10) / 10.0) * 10.0
    randAppleY = round(random.randrange(30, window.display_height - food_size - 10) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not gameExit:
        if gameOver == True:
            outro()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -snake_size
                    y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = snake_size
                    y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -snake_size
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = snake_size
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(green)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [0, 0, 10, 600])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [10, 0, 780, 30])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [10, 5, 780, 20])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [790, 0, 10, 600])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [10, 590, 780, 10])
        scoreMessage(score)
        levelMessage(level)

        if x > window.display_width - 10:
                gameOver = True
                wynik = open('wynik', 'a')
                wynik.write(',' + str(score))

        elif x < 10:
                gameOver = True
                wynik = open('wynik', 'a')
                wynik.write(',' + str(score))

        elif y > window.display_height - 10:
                gameOver = True
                wynik = open('wynik', 'a')
                wynik.write(',' + str(score))

        elif y < 30:
                gameOver = True
                wynik = open('wynik', 'a')
                wynik.write(',' + str(score))



        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [randAppleX, randAppleY, food_size, food_size])

        snakeHead = []
        snakeHead.append(x)
        snakeHead.append(y)
        snakeList.append(snakeHead)

        if len(snakeList) > snakeLength:
            del snakeList[0]

        for eachSegment in snakeList[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == snakeHead:
                gameOver = True

        snake(snake_size, snakeList)

        pygame.display.update()

        if x == randAppleX and y == randAppleY:
            randAppleX = round(random.randrange(15, window.display_width - food_size - 10) / 10.0) * 10.0
            randAppleY = round(random.randrange(30, window.display_height - food_size - 10) / 10.0) * 10.0
            snakeLength += 1
            score += 1

        if score <= 4:
            clock.tick(window.FPS)
            level = 1
        if score > 4 and score <= 9:
            clock.tick(20)
            level = 2
        if score > 9:
            clock.tick(25)
            level = 3

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

intro()
gameLoop()
outro()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information: Python version, complete pyinstaller error,  ...

Comment: code on pastebin is OK for that one I guess, but what we would _really_ need is the exact stacktrace.

Comment: Python 3.5, where do I find a complete list of errors that show in the command window?

Comment: pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip from https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2184

Comment: No error after instaling github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip but when i open the .exe file it says that waz.exe stopped working